# Why won't this simple SQL statement work?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, datetime, timestamp

`dateposted` is a MySQL TIMESTAMP column:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM posts 
  WHERE dateposted > NOW() - 604800
```

...*SHOULD*, if I am not mistaken, return rows where `dateposted` was in the last week. But it returns only posts less than roughly one day old.  I was under the impression that `TIMESTAMP` used seconds?

IE: 7 * 3600 * 24 = 604800

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE dateposted BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: +1 I would expect this solution to benefit from an index more than the answer I gave.

Comment: Exactumundo! Thank you. I dont know how i got SQL like this to work in my last website.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `now()` is implicitly converted into a number from timestamp and mysql conversion rules create a number like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu

from mysql docs:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
        -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT NOW() + 0;
        -> 20071215235026.000000
```

Comment: FINALLY it makes sense. I was under the impression it changed to the UNIX_TIMESTAMP. thanks.

Comment: Ugh, it really changes the interpretation of the data from underneath you?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't implicitly use integer arithmetic with `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME`, and other date-related data types.  You're thinking of the UNIX timestamp format, which is an integer number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

You can convert SQL data types to a [UNIX timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) in MySQL and then use arithmetic:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateposted)+604800 > NOW()+0;
```

NB: adding zero to [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) makes it return a numeric value instead of a string value.

---

**update:** Okay, I'm totally wrong with the above query.  Converting `NOW()` to a numeric output *doesn't* produce a number that can be compared to UNIX timestamps.  It produces a number, but the number doesn't count seconds or anything else.  The digits are just YYYYMMDDHHMMSS strung together.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  dateposted TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO foo (dateposted) VALUES ('2009-12-4'), ('2009-12-11'), ('2009-12-18');

SELECT * FROM foo;

+----+---------------------+
| id | dateposted          |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2009-12-04 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2009-12-11 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 2009-12-18 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+

SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateposted) AS ut, NOW()-604800 AS wk FROM foo

+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| id | dateposted          | ut         | wk                    |
+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | 2009-12-04 00:00:00 | 1259913600 | 20091223539359.000000 |
|  2 | 2009-12-11 00:00:00 | 1260518400 | 20091223539359.000000 |
|  3 | 2009-12-18 00:00:00 | 1261123200 | 20091223539359.000000 |
+----+---------------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

It's clear that the numeric values are not comparable.  However, `UNIX_TIMSTAMP()` can also convert numeric values in that format as it can convert a string representation of a timestamp:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateposted) AS ut, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-604800 AS wk FROM foo

+----+---------------------+------------+------------+
| id | dateposted          | ut         | wk         |
+----+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2009-12-04 00:00:00 | 1259913600 | 1261089774 |
|  2 | 2009-12-11 00:00:00 | 1260518400 | 1261089774 |
|  3 | 2009-12-18 00:00:00 | 1261123200 | 1261089774 |
+----+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Now one can run a query with an expression comparing them:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateposted) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-604800

+----+---------------------+
| id | dateposted          |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | 2009-12-18 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

But the answer given by @OMGPonies is still better, because this expression in my query probably can't make use of an index.  I'm just offering this as an explanation of how the `TIMESTAMP` and `NOW()` features work.

Comment: Is there some reason this would be preferred over simply using the date math functions?

Comment: No, I upvoted the answer from @OMGPonies and I would prefer that usage.  I show the expression above only because it's more similar to the OP's query.

Comment: Then why was it still showing results instead of an error? I am confused. Well the first thing i tried before posting this was to do UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateposted)> NOW() - 604800, but that (as does yours) returned an empty set.

Comment: @Douglas: I suppose if you are using your original query format then you are supposed to subtract 7000000 (seven million), because this is the way of implicit timestamp conversion (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Internally perhaps. The way to do this is the date math functions. So it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE dateposted > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

I think there is a DATE_SUB, I'm just used to using ADD everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) < dateposted;
```

I am assuming that you are using mySQL.